# Insert type double into the database

Tags: anylogic

I would like to insert different numbers of type double (1.2 1.5) instead of type int into my process flow. I always get an error. Is it possible to insert DOUBLE instead of INT into my process flow with source? I use the pallet racks where the number N pallets will be insert.

[image: database]

Answer (score 0):

You can easily convert your dbase int value to a double using `(double)myIntValue`

But I fear you are actually asking a slightly different question. Please always include your error msg and the code snippet it refers to, much easier to see the real issue ;)